# http Request to https webservice?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. From what I've read you can't make an http request to an https web service. So when an app is live on a phone how can you make a request to an https web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried it ?

Because I'm working on an app developed with PhoneGap and Sencha Touch and HTTP Request to a HTTPS web service works just fine.

**Update**

Try to add this at the end of you AppDelegate.m file

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; 
}
@end
```

Comment: I`ve only tried it via the iPhone/ iPad simulator. So maybe it will work they way its supposed to on a device.

Comment: I added an * to the whitelist (I'm developing it locally), if I add localhost or 127.0.0.1 to the whitelist the ajax requests don't work.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being vague, and thanks for taking the time to help me :) when the * is added to the external hosts array I can make http requests to a small web service I've written and that works great. The problem is when I try to make an https request to the web service nothing happens. https is available. Does this have anything to do with the certificate not being trusted?